# raml with trait injecting query params

Tags: mule, mulesoft, apikit

I am working at a place which makes heavy use of mule and I am relatively a noob.
One of the things that I am unable to understand is - we have an existing RAML with traits
Example of RAML snippet:

```
/:
  description: Employee Resource
  get:
    description: Get all employees
    is: [ pageable ]
```

Here is snippet from 'pageable' trait:

```
queryParameters:
 offset:
  description: Specific page, starting from 1
  type: integer
  required: false
  example: 40
  default: 1
```

This is a Mule API with an APIKitRouter .

When I run this api in debug mode and do **NOT** send a request with this query param : **offset**

I can see that we dont have a query param ( in 'InboundProperties' ) .
However as soon as the code passes through 'APIKitRouter' mule is injecting this query param into 'InboundProperties' ( this is a Mule 3 api )

I am aware that APIKitRouter contains a definition / reference to the RAML
What I do not understand is :
why is mule injecting this query param ?
Thanks

edit1 :
here is the screen print of inbound with injected query param in debug mode:
[image]

Comment: What is the content of inboundProperties exactly? What are you seeing exactly? Please show the keys and values.

Comment: @aled edited - have added image above showing injected value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that APIkit is injecting the offset query parameter because it has a default value of 1 in the trait. Since you are not actually sending it in the HTTP request it is adding it with default value.

Comment: Thanks yes , but suprisingly atleast wherever I searched , the documentation does not talk about it , as a result while making some changes was a little suprised with this behaviour